# MySQL Return Max and Min Values Based on ID

Tags: mysql

I have very little experience with relational databases and am struggling to figure out what I think is a fairly simple SQL query. I'm dealing with a table similar to below:

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| id |  type  | start_date |  end_date  |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | type_1 | 2010-04-01 | 2011-04-01 |
|  1 | type_1 | 2011-04-02 | 2012-04-02 |
|  2 | type_1 | 2008-04-01 | 2010-04-01 |
|  2 | type_1 | 2010-04-02 | 2015-04-02 |
|  2 | type_1 | 2015-04-03 | 2016-04-03 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to return the earliest start_date and latest end_date for each id in the table, so the result would look like:

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| id |  type  | start_date |  end_date  |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | type_1 | 2010-04-01 | 2012-04-02 |
|  2 | type_1 | 2008-04-01 | 2016-04-03 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
```

Again, I'm sorry if this is an easy question, but databases are not my primary responsibility. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: _“but databases are not my primary responsibility”_ - well then let the person whose responsibility they are deal with it …? I can’t really see this as a valid excuse for a poorly researched question.

Answer (score 0):

you could use min() max() and group by id

```
  select id, min(start_date), max(end_date)
  from my_table 
  group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use min and max to find the earliest and latest date within a sub query so you can select type as well.

```
SELECT tablename.id, type, start, end
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, MIN(start_date) AS start, MAX(end_date) AS end
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY id 
) a
INNER JOIN tablename on tablename.id = a.id
```